# Spring Actuator Change Host

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openshift, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying setup Spring Actuator with Spring Boot admin Server. In my local machine work fine, but in openshift cloud I have some problems...

**Local**:

```
d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Application registered itself as {id=93a4432e, name=orbe, managementUrl=http://localhost:8080/orbe, healthUrl=http://localhost:8080/orbe/status, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8080/orbe, statusInfo={}}}, source=http-api, metadata={}, info={}}
```

**Cloud**:

```
d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Application registered itself as {id=7068c1d1, name=orbe, managementUrl=http://orbe-api-334-ciunv:8080/orbe, healthUrl=http://orbe-api-334-ciunv:8080/orbe/status, serviceUrl=http://orbe-api-334-ciunv:8080/orbe, statusInfo={status=UNKNOWN, timestamp=1496071160897, details={}}, source=http-api, metadata={}, info={}}
```

In local, application have correct HOST (localhost), but in cloud Openshift (Kubernetes) hostname is the POD name container and is not working (Spring Boot Admin is not detected the app and health check return UNKNOWN.

Please, can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution, override management-url in application.yml:

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        management-url: http://remote-docker-host:8080 #docker host
```

UPDATE Spring boot 2.0:

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: http://spring-boot-admin-server-url:8080
        instance:
          service-url: http://you-application-url:8080
```